# Test if Element exists Vuejs, Karma, Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, vue.js, karma-mocha

I'm new to testing in Javascript and Vue.js.  I installed vue via vue-cli and the full webpack template that has Karma, Mocha, and PhantomJS built in. I ran the hello world component test and it passes.

I have a vuejs component called `my-input.vue` that generates the following HTML.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input class="test-focused">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

I have a test for the component that looks like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { default as MyInput } from 'src/components/my-input.vue'

describe('my-input.vue', () => {
  it('should display an input element', () => {
    const expected = "<input class='test-focused'>"

    const vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><my-input></my-input></div>',
      components: { 'my-input': MyInput }
    }).$mount()

    // I tried these separately.
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('input.test-focused').isPresent()).to.be.true

    expect(document.getElementsByTagName('input').indexOf(expected) != -1).to.be.true
  })
})
```

When I run the each of the expect() statements separately I get `undefined is not a constructor`.

It seems like this is a dirt simple test.

**How do I properly test for the existence of an element?**

Also, if you can point me to documentation about what methods are available for `vm.$el.querySelector('input.test-focused')`, as well as, `expect()` it would help. Disambiguating syntax for Jasmine, Mocha, and other beverages seems to make testing harder than it needs `toBe()` or `not.to.be`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9mdqw53b/

```
const MyInput = { template: '<input class="test-focused">' }

describe('my-input.vue', () => {
  it('should display an input element', () => {
    const vm = new Vue({
      template: '<div><my-input></my-input></div>',
      components: { MyInput }
    }).$mount()

    // I tried these separately.
    expect(vm.$el.querySelectorAll('input.test-focused').length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

expect(vm.$el.querySelector('input.test-focused') !== null).to.be.true